# How to create a zip folder with dependancies for aws device farm

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, junit, android-gradle-plugin, appium

I`m trying to achieve this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html

using gradle...not maven. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I work for the device farm team.

We provide the packaging instructions using maven to provide a consistent experience across all test frameworks. 
What we eventually are looking for are 2 jar files (containing code under src/main and src/tests) and a dependency jar folder containing all the jar files used by your test.
We currently do not have a out of the box way of packaging your tests using gradle. 
However, setting up maven should not be hard as most of the customers follow the instructions to the dot and are able to get through it.

If you aren't able to proceed I would suggest opening a thread on AWS forums and we can follow up on that to help you get there.